# Unable to save/edit nodes if Image Field containts more than 26 values

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a gallery content-type using Image field to upload multiple pictures to a node. Everything is well if I upload only a few pictures. But when trying to upload +26 pictures I get the following message after each upload "Gallery X has been updated." (I did not press save). At the same time, the Image field disappears.

Afterwards, when trying to press save I get "The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or you have already submitted modifications using this form. As a result, your changes cannot be saved." message.

Closing the node without saving, the node contains all uploaded pictures, BUT I am now unable to do the following with the node:

- Any changes in publish/unpublish, url-alias, revisions, etc. are not saved. Clicking save will prompt the "Node X has been updated." message but changes are not saved.
- When I try to upload additional pictures (picture 28,29,30...) I get again get the "Node X has been updated." message, the Image field disappears, and I am again unable to save using the save button.

This issue has also occurred a few times with failed uploads, but when trying to reproduce it, it happens every time at picture no 27 on my Drupal 7.12. This is an issue I have been struggling with for some time, and I have also posted it in the Drupal issue stack: http://drupal.org/node/1468522.

Thanks, Lars Bo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now spend the whole day testing for this issue. It turns up in both Drupal 7, 7.10 and 7.12. Luckily, that makes sense since **the problem was hiding with PHP**. My server was using php 5.2.0 and apparently the Image Field code requires at least php 5.2.5 to work properly (it turns out that php 5.2.5 is the official minimum for Drupal 7 while 5.3 is recommended). **I put my server on PHP 5.3 and now everything works** as expected. I can upload as many pictures as I like and no strange behaviour or error messages. This was really hard to debug...

Answer (score 1):

had a similar problem! When I download a lot of images ( 70+ and more) , then the node is not saved, was not published, it was not possible to change the body text, was not upload new images.
Problems lies in the parameter max_input_var in php.ini

**Solution**:
As explained in documentation, this directive may only be set per directory scope, which means via .htaccess file, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3).

See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Adding the directive into php.ini or placing following lines into .htaccess will work:

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this error.  Have you tried it on a fresh core install with just an image field?  Are your modules up to date?

What are you using to upload 26+ pictures? Bulk uploading like Plupload? or one by one?  We need more information.

Comment: My core is 7.12 and all modules are up to date. I have now done several tests like so: I create a new test content type, add a image field with unlimited values allowed, and then I start uploading images.. Every time I hit picture 26 the described issue occurs. Since I only use the ImageField supplied with core I do not think my other modules are interfering.